# How to Install vue3 in Laravel 8 without vue-scaffolding or without installing breeze / jetstream with Inertia+vue

Tags: laravel-8, vuejs3

I have install Laravel 8 fresh project. And for authentication scaffolding I have run:

```
composer require Laravel/breeze --dev
```

It generate Laravel build-in authentication functionality which is now components base.
Now my question is, now are not generating Auth by using Laravel Ui package. So the vue scaffolding is not generated so how we can use vue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can install vue3 in Laravel 8 without vue-scaffolding by following instructions given in below video:
[Install vue3 in Laravel 8 without Laravel UI / breeze / Jetstream](https://laracasts.com/series/whats-new-in-vue-3/episodes/14)