# Problem getting updated value from child component to the parent component in a Laravel 9 with Vue

Tags: laravel, vue-component

I am using a Laravel 9 application with Vue 3. I have created a fresh install.
I want to create some components that I want to use in a parent component. The first component that I want to create is  which will be passed a value (postal code) and the component will format and validate the passed value. The parent component should have access to the updated formatted value.

As a first step, I have created the postal-code-component using the documentation from vuejs.org.

```
<!-- postalcode.vue -->
<script>
export default {
  props: ['modelValue'],
  emits: ['update:modelValue'],
  computed: {
    value: {
      get() {
        return this.modelValue;
      },
      set(value) {
        this.$emit('update:modelValue', value)
      }
    }
  }
}
</script>

<template>
  <input v-model="value" />
</template>
```

Next, I made a copy of the example-component, that comes with the Laravel Vue installation to create a data element "postalcode" and use as a v-model for ,

```
    <div class="card-body">
        <postal-code-input v-model="postalcode" /> {{ postalcode }}
    </div>
</template>

<script>
    export default {
    data(){
        return {
            postalcode:'l3r3g',
        }
    },
}
```

When I run my app, it displays the initial value (l3r3g) in the input box and also the same value at {{postalcode}}. However, when I update the value in the input box, it does not update {{postalcode}} in the parent component. When I inspect the  component in vue dev tools, I see that modelValue and computed 'value' are undefined, as shown

[image]

I just don't know what is going on. I shall appreciate any help to fix this issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've tried by using `watcher` instead of `computed` property because the computed properties made cache and sometime it's `set()` method created complications in debugging `reactivity`.

**Following snippet works for me:**

```
// PostalCode.vue

<template>
    <div class="input-group  input-group-merge mb-3">
        <input
            v-model="postalCode"
            type="text" class="form-control"
            id="postal_code" name="postal_code"
        />
    </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
    name: "PostalCode",

    props: {
        modelValue: String,
    },

    data() {
        return {
            postalCode: null
        }
    },

    watch: {
        // watching prop
        modelValue: {
            handler: function (newValue) {
                if (newValue) {
                    this.postalCode = newValue;
                }
            },
            immediate: true,
        },

       // watching data() property
        postalCode: {
            handler: function (newValue, old) {            
                this.$emit('update:modelValue', newValue)
            },
            immediate: true
        }
    }
}
</script>
```

##### Usage:

```
<postal-code v-model="user.postal_code"/>
```

Your can also place your formatting logic within any watcher also.

##### Hint/Suggestion:

depending on requirement, if you want to do formatting on props change by parent (for old and new both) then place formatting logic in `modelValue` watcher.

##### Note:

Following snippet works perfectly on `Vue3`

Comment: I tried your scheme. However, this is not passing the postal code from parent to the child, i.e. the input textbox is empty when the page loads. Also, the updated value is not reflecting in the parent component. I believe that it is working in Vue 3 for you. I am guessing that perhaps using this within Laravel 9 is causing this issue. Other than this, I am using complex child components that emit data through events, and everything  works fine.

Comment: can you share me `dev-tool` screen-shot of my schema. and also `json.package`  code in your question by editing it?

Comment: I've implemented in vue3 within the Laravel8

Comment: I've tested in fresh Laravel-project. you can clone my project from below given repository : 
`https://github.com/M-khawar/postalcode-component-example`

Comment: I cloned your repository, and indeed it works. Thanks. I will see what is different between your code and mine. Thanks once again for your special efforts.

Comment: While your code for Laravel 8 works, I am unable to make it work in Laravel 9. If you have time, could you please clone my repo and test. https://github.com/rktaxali/parent_child_component.git

Comment: @user761100 I've cloned and seen your `package.json` file. you are using `vue: ^2.6.12` that's why it is not working. I just modified `postal-code` component according to `vue2` syntax.  I've sent you a pull request on your `repository`, please do merge and your code will starts to work perfectly. If you want to upgrade your vue version from `vue2 => vue3` , you can follow https://stackoverflow.com/a/67341974/12719616 thread.

Comment: Thank you so much for your help. After merging your changes, the child component started working. I would upgrade my project to use Vue 3 as per the link you have provided. When I installed my Laravel 9 project, I incorrectly assumed that it would install the latest version of Vue. Thanks once again for your help.

Answer (score 0):

If you’re using v-model to bind a prop like this

```
<postal-code-input v-model="postalcode" />
```

The postal-code component should emit ‘input’ and have a value prop. You can use a different prop and event but then you should avoid the v-model binding and just do something like this

```
<postal-code-input :modelValue="postalcode" @modelValueUpdate=“handleUpdate” />
```

Comment: as you have said, the child component should emit the input value, however, it is not doing it. The Vue.js documentation and all the tutorials and YouTube videos recommend the scheme that I have used. But it does not work for me!

Comment: Its because you're using a different event name 'update:modelValue' the v-model binding you are using doesn't act on this event

Comment: you are suggesting to use @modelValueUpdate=“handleUpdate”, i.e I need to have a method to handle events emitted by the child component. I know about thus and have used this with complex child components. However, this time, I want to create a simple child component that is self contained and does not require any event handling by parent.

Comment: Then use this.$emit('input', newValue)